# How to change a row color of DataGridView based on Condition to check if Date Expired

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

What I want to achieve is to dynamically change the color of the row of `datagridview` based on a condition that is mentioned in the code below which means if the Expiry Date is greater than the current date which means its expired then the Row changed its color to red
And if 30 days remain in Expiration than turn yellow

```
private void ViewMedicine_DataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (Dont know what to write here)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows) 
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused by your statement…  _”if the E_Date (Expiry Date) is greater than the current date which means its expired”_ …? … This seems backwards and should be _“if E_Date is LESS THAN the current date, then E_Date is expired”_ … Am I missing something? In either case, checking if a date is before or after the “current date” would look something like… `if (E_Date.Date < DateTime.Now.Date) { // E_Date is expired };`

Comment: @JohnG I have make changes in the question as earlier it was making confusion due to SQL Query Part and Made it simple so one can not be confused.

Comment: @JohnG Also Posted the answer as I solved this issue Please check

Comment: You may want to note… that putting the code into the grids `RowPrePaint` event means that the code will check the dates and color the rows even if the date has not changed. Example... when the user “scrolls” the grid, the grids `RowPrePaint` event will fire and check the dates and color the row, when it is already the correct color. You should be careful which grid event(s) you put the code in to avoid executing it unnecessarily. This can lead to a sluggish UI.

Comment: Also I am still not understanding how a date can be “expired” if the date is AFTER the current date. This seems backwards to me… however, if it works for you, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you could use two nested `for`, one to loop your results from the query (DataTable MrkExp), one to loop the values contained in your `dataGridView`.

Assuming both of your database's table and dataGridView have one Unique ID or field, you could check if they're equal.

To achieve that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < MrkExp.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
                        {
                            if (ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == MrkExp.Rows[j]["UNIQUE_FIELD"])
                            {
                                ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If you haven't got a unique field or primary, consider updating your question showing your table's structure.

Comment: Posted an Answer as I solved this question Please Check

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a little brainstorming into the code and research a bit I got successful in getting the desired result. Here's what I code to made it possible using a `RowPrePaint` Event

```
private void ViewMedicine_DataGrid_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var ExpiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
            var TodayDate = DateTime.Today;
            var Expired = ExpiryDate >= TodayDate;
            var ExpiredToBe = ExpiryDate >= TodayDate.AddDays(-30);
            if (Expired)
            {
                ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (ExpiredToBe)
            {
                ViewMedicine_DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
```

Before I was using a `CellFormatting` event which was wrong and Created a `RowPrePaint` Event and before `if` statements declared variables to be used in `if` Statement and the code I used shows the rest. It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use the [event DataGridViewCell.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) for this. It is called, whenever cell [x, y] needs to be formatted.

### Use DataBinding to easily access the data in your rows

I don't know what kind of items you show in your DataGridView, let's assume it's a collection of price offers. Each price offer has an expiry date:

```
class PriceOffer
{
    public DateTime ExpiryDate {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Somewhere you tell which columns of the PriceOffer needs to be shown. Probably in the constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();

this.ColumnStartDate.DataPropertyName = nameof(PriceOffer.StartDate);
this.ColumnExpiryDate.DataPropertyName = nameof(PriceOffer.ExpiryDate);
this.ColumnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(PriceOffer.Price);
...
```

You also have a property to get your initial collection of PriceOffers:

```
IEnumerable<PriceOffer> FetchPriceOffersToDisplay(...)
{
    return ...
}
```

And of course a property to attach these PriceOffers to the DataGridView

```
BindingList<PriceOffer> DisplayedPriceOffers
{
    get => return (BindingList<PriceOffer>)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}
```

Initialize when the form is loaded

```
void OnFormLoad(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayedPriceOffers = new BindingList<PriceOffer>(
        this.FetchPriceOffersToDisplay().ToList());
}
```

All changes that the operator makes: add / remove / edit PriceOffers are automatically updated in `this.DisplayedPriceOffers`.

### Back to your question

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    PriceOffer priceOffer = (PriceOffer)row.DataboundItem;
    
    if (DateTime.Today > priceOffer.ExpiryDate)
    {
        this.ColorRowExpired(row);
    }
    else
    {
        this.ColorRowNotExpired(row);
    }
}

void ColorRowExpired(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.BackColor = ExpiredCellBackColor;
        ...
    }
}
```